# Partial para separação de eventos e métodos

Tags: c#, .net, classes, wpf, partial

Eu vi em um sistema uma separação dos métodos em uma `partial` e os eventos em outra em `UserControl` e `Window` conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
"Pessoa.xaml.cs"
public partial class Pessoa: UserControl
{
    //Construtor
    //Somente Eventos Exp: Click dos botões
}

"Pessoa.cs"
public partial class Pessoa
{
    //Somente Métodos Exp: Metodo Inserir

}
```

Isto é correto fazer?

Tem algum ganho de performance?

Ou deve ter sido feito apenas para organização?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só organização, não muda nada na execução.

Algumas pessoas consideram que `partial` só deve ser usado por ferramentas de geração de código (o que muitas vezes é o caso de eventos), assim a parte gerada fica em um arquivo que o programador não deve por a mão e o que ele pode mexer fica em outro arquivo.

Outros não são tão radicais, afinal, é raro ser um problema. A separação pode ocorrer por outros fatores, até de separação de responsabilidades dentro da equipe. Um comum é quando um tipo está muito grande e faz sentido tipos grandes, ao contrário do que alguns pregam.

O que deve-se evitar é simular herança clássica, *trait* ou coisas do tipo com `partial`. Mesmo isso eu diria só para evitar, não para não fazer nunca.

Comment: Bigown obrigado. Esclareceu.