# Como implementar funcionalidades customizadas em um model no .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, classes, partial

Eu precisei implementar algumas funcionalidades no model `users` mas como vocês podem ver logo no início esta classe é gerada automaticamente pela Entity, então sempre que eu atualizar ou recriar o model as funcionalidades customizadas serão perdidas.

Exemplo de uma implementação customizada feito no model `users`:

```
public string full_name
{
    get
    {
        return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
    }
}
```

Há alguma forma de sobrescrever o model para manter estas funcionalidades customizadas sem que sejam sobrescrevidas sempre que eu atualizar / recriar o model?

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace E_Learning.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using E_Learning.Helpers;

    public partial class users
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public users()
        {
            this.updated_at = DateTime.Now;
            this.created_at = DateTime.Now;

            this.signatures = new HashSet<signatures>();
            this.testimonials = new HashSet<testimonials>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string identity_ { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> birthday { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> sexuality { get; set; }
        public string remember_token { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> status { get; set; }
        public string handle { get; set; }

        public string setHandle ()
        {
            return Slugify.Make(this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name);
        }

        public string full_name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
            }
        }

        private Nullable<int> age
        {
            get
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Today;

                if (this.birthday.HasValue)
                {
                    DateTime birthday = DateTime.Parse(this.birthday.ToString());
                    int age = now.Year - birthday.Year;

                    if (now < birthday.AddYears(age))
                        age--;

                    return age;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<signatures> signatures { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<testimonials> testimonials { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto já foi mais ou menos respondido em [Como editar uma Partial Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77528/101)

As classes parciais existem justamente para este tipo de problema. Você cria as customizações em um arquivo separado que será compilado junto.

É claro que você não pode mexer em nada do arquivo gerado. Isto sempre será perdido quando atualizar o *model*. Tem que achar uma organização e até criar padrões de projeto para desacoplar uma parte da outra se tiver algumas coisas mais complexas para fazer (na maioria dos casos é só ter métodos simples mesmo).

Então crie um outro arquivo com `class partial Users` e faça o que precisar ali. Note que a classe já foi gerada com esta intenção.

Você não pode sobrepor uma propriedade existente. O que pode fazer é criar uma outra que chame a original criada pelo EF. Só a propriedade do EF será persistida, a sua será auxiliar. Pode não ser o ideal, mas até onde eu sei não tem outra forma. No seu exemplo, funcionará perfeitamente, `FullName` é uma ótima propriedade complementar para `FirstName` e `LastName`.

Dependendo do que for fazer pode [adicionar complementos para o modelo gerado em uma classe de metadados](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Não parece ser o que deseja, mas é uma alternativa em alguns casos.

No futuro talvez terá o `supersedes` ou algo do tipo. Acredito que ele seja feito sob medida para este problema. Então você poderá dizer na classe parcial que uma propriedade deve substituir a outra gerada na outra parte da classe, mais ou menos como se fosse um método virtual (claro que o mecanismo é bem mais simples e resolvido todo em compilação).

Um exemplo é o uso de eventos: [Partial para separação de eventos e métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124453/101). Exemplo com WPF: [Centralizar (usar apenas um) um try-catch para toda aplicação WPF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104714/101). Exemplo com ASP.NET: [Erro ao adicionar valor do While no List<>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39080/101)

Pode ajudar: [Criar método parcial (partial) no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44333/101)

Outra solução é adotar o [Model First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/model-first-with-entity-framework.aspx) que acaba com este problema e é o futuro do EF, o presente no EF Core.

Answer (score 4):

Um dos princípios de programação orientada à objetos, SOLID, é que um objeto deve ser fechado para manutenção, mas aberto para extensão.

Para adicionar funcionalidades em um objeto fechado para manutenção, basta estende-lo. Veja:

```
public static class UserExtensions
{
    public static string FullName(this User user) =>        
         $"{user.first_name} {user.last_name}";
}
```

E depois basta consumir:

```
var usuario = new User { first_name = "Thiago", last_name = "Lunardi" };
Console.WriteLine( usuario.FullName() ); // Thiago Lunardi
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/135ZcB).

Veja mais neste artigo sobre [SOLID - OCP - Open/Closed Principles](http://eduardopires.net.br/2016/01/solid-ocp-extension-methods/).

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer isso, você pode criar um projeto de ViewModels na sua aplicação, e adicionar um metadata que associa ao seu Model do Entity. Exemplo:

```
namespace E_Learning.ViewModels
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(E_Learning.Models.users))]
    public partial class users
    {

    }
}
```

Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx

Comment: Bom uso de classes `partial`. Porém, o *pattern* `ViewModel` não tem esse fim. Nesta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126551/3825) falo sobre o uso ideal dele.