# Chamar um método automaticamente através de uma partial class no .NET

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, classes, partial

Criei uma `partial class` para o *model* `users` onde implementei algumas funções customizadas, como por exemplo, uma função que pega o nome e sobrenome atribuídos e gera um `handle`, veja no exemplo a seguir:

```
namespace E_Learning.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using E_Learning.Helpers;

    public partial class users
    {
        public string makeHandle()
        {
            return Slugify.Make(this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name);
        }

        public string full_name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
            }
        }

        private Nullable<int> age
        {
            get
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Today;

                if (this.birthday.HasValue)
                {
                    DateTime birthday = DateTime.Parse(this.birthday.ToString());
                    int age = now.Year - birthday.Year;

                    if (now < birthday.AddYears(age))
                        age--;

                    return age;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Coisa simples. Porém ao inserir uma nova instância no banco eu tenho sempre que chamar manualmente o `user.handle = user.makeHandle()`, mas eu gostaria de poder "sobrescrever" o método `.add()` ou o *model* `users` para sempre que ao criar uma nova instância e atribuir os valores, o método `makeHandle()` seja chamado automaticamente. É possível fazer essa chamada direto da `partial class`?

```
public ActionResult Index(Entities db)
{
    string password = BCryptHelper.HashPassword("admin", BCryptHelper.GenerateSalt(8));

    users user = new users
    {
        first_name = "Rafael",
        last_name = "Alexandre",
        email = "rafael.alexandre@exemple.com",
        password = password,
    };

    user.handle = user.makeHandle();
    db.Set<users>().Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml");
}
```

O Model:

```
namespace E_Learning.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using E_Learning.Helpers;

    public partial class users
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public users()
        {
            this.signatures = new HashSet<signatures>();
            this.testimonials = new HashSet<testimonials>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string identity_ { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> birthday { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> sexuality { get; set; }
        public string remember_token { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> status { get; set; }
        public string handle { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<signatures> signatures { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<testimonials> testimonials { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OBS: renomeei o método `getHandle()` para `makeHandle()` para que não gere uma confusão... porque o método chamado agora de `makeHandle()` deverá ser chamado apenas no `set;` mas no `get;` o valor retornado é o mesmo instanciado na coluna `handle` da tabela no banco.

Comment: Já tentou colocar no construtor o método users#getHandle?

Comment: Sim, mas no construtor o handle volta vazio porque as variáveis first_name e last_name são preenchidas após o construtor inciar.

Comment: A propriedade *handle* pode receber qualquer outro valor de um consumidor da classe, ou deve ser sempre consituída do valor montado a partir de nome + sobrenome? Será que o *handle*, por ser um valor calculado, não deveria ser somente leitura para consumidores da classe? E não está muito certo isso de o *set* alterar a propriedade na instância e o *get* continuar retornando o valor que estava lá antes (valor do banco na hora de obter a entidade).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Respondendo especificamente a pergunta feita, até onde eu sei, com o `Add()` não é possível. Sei que [dá para mexer no `SaveChanges()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/cc716714(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas aí é tarde demais.

O ideal seria realmente ter uma forma reativa de uma alteração em um das propriedades da entidade já gerasse a mudança na propriedade `handle`. Seria possível criar propriedades `FirstName` e `LastName` em substituição às `first_name` e `last_name`. Mas não teria como proibir o uso destas.

Como o AP agora diz (em comentário) que isto é possível, então a melhor solução é alterar as propriedades já existentes para para que elas manipulem a propriedade, aí ao invés de uma propriedade automática, pode definir o comportamento que ela deve ter. Isto vai contra ao que foi perguntado, afinal pra que usar classe parcial se pode mexer no código da propriedade?

```
private string _first_name;
public string first_name { 
    get => _first_name;
    set { 
        _first_name = value; 
        handle = getHandle(); 
    }
}
private string _last_name;
public string last_name { 
    get => _last_name;
    set { 
        _last_name = value; 
        handle = getHandle(); 
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/AditionalHandle.cs).

## Alternativas

Se ainda quiser mexer nas propriedades em tempo posterior ao da manipulação da entidade, pode ter uma saída.

[Conversando com o Cigano no *chat*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29441037#29441037) ele falou sobre a interface [`IValidatableObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Você pode usar esta oportunidade para na validação do objeto fazer a escrita na propriedade de forma automática. Normalmente isto seria usado só para validar, mas nada impede que seja usada também para alterar algum membro da entidade, mantendo o estado válido.

Exemplo de implementação em [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401178/221800).

Também em conversa no chat se falou da possibilidade de criação de um repositório que se sobreponha ao existente no EF, mas não me parece uma boa solução. Se fizer isto, pode controlar tudo o que pode fazer em cada momento, mas teria que recriar algo já existente e deve ser por isso que resolveu usar o EF, não pra ficar o recriando.

Me parece que solução seria resolver melhor o que foi [perguntado antes pelo AP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126746/101).

Answer (score 2):

Você deve ser explícito para disparar esse `handler`. Agora, o local onde ele está sendo disparado é que deveria estar centralizado. Senão terá que fazer uma chamada dessas a cada vez que alterar as propriedades desse objeto.

Notavelmente você está usando classes criadas automaticamente por algum tipo de engenharia reversa para criar suas *models* e demais entidades. Acredito ser por isso que está tendo dificuldades em dar alguma manutenção.

Eu tenho um exemplo no GitHub sobre como construir aplicações com separação de camadas por responsabilidade.

Eu creio que pode te ajudar a ter um maior controle dos códigos de sua aplicação, e também irá reduzir muito o custo de manutenção pós implantação.

[MVC Music Store - GitHub](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/MvcMusicStoreDDD)

[ASP.NET MVC Implementando DDD, SOLID, DI, IOC e SelfValidation](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/02/aspnet-mvc-implementando-ddd-tdd-solid-di-ioc-crosscutting-selfvalidation/)

Answer (score 2):

Não se esqueça que a sua propriedade *handle* tem um *getter*, onde você pode escrever qualquer código, inclusive fazendo este *getter* retornar o resultado da função *makeHandle()*:

```
public string handle 
{ 
    get { return makeHandle(); }
}
```

Simples, não?

Existem várias outras opções, como construir o *handle* na medida em que as propriedades envolvidas são setadas, por exemplo:

```
private string _first_name;
public string first_name 
{ 
    get { return _first_name; }
    set
    { 
        _first_name = value; 
        handle = makeHandle(); 
    }
}

private string _last_name ;
public string last_name 
{ 
    get { return _last_name; }
    set
    { 
        _last_name = value; 
        handle = makeHandle(); 
    }
}
```

Parece não haver necessidade de envolver o Entity Framework nisso. Trabalhar só com os *getters* e *setters* é mais simples.

Comment: @RafaelAlexandre agora você pode mexer na propriedade ou continua não podendo mexer nela?

Comment: Sim, agora posso.

Comment: @RafaelAlexandre deveria ter colocado isto na pergunta. Acho estranho que agora possa, mas vou na sua, vou editar minha resposta só para reforçar o que eu já havia respondido.